# From HTTP response to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I need to export data from URL to csv, this code works, but data which located on this URL writes in one string without delimiters, how to solve it?

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd

URL="https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/emb/vci/NPP_VH/4km/ts_L1_v1/ByWeek/VHP_L1_Mean_198135.txt"
vhi_url = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
out = open('vhi_id_16.csv','wb')
out.write(vhi_url.read())
out.close()
```

Comment: Considering extension of `VHP_L1_Mean_198135.txt` file you're downloading is not a CSV... So how do you want Python to know that you need to transform plain text into CSV?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(vhi_url.read(100))`

Comment: It's better to write textual files by using the textual mode - `w` instead of `wb`.

Comment: @MrMister: Please explain why?

Comment: @Andersson I saw the topics where url with data in json transformed in csv and thought that is can be with plain text

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко , yes but you should make *transformation*. Did you try anything to make CSV from text?

Comment: @Andersson If you read the title of the topic and my question, you will see that I ask how to solve this problem and possible solutions.

Comment: @stovfl Python will automatically convert line endings, depending on the operating system, if you use the textual mode. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1):

Use this slight variation of your code:

```
from urllib import request

with open('vhi_id_16.csv', 'w') as out:
    with request.urlopen('PUT_URL_HERE') as response:
        encoding = response.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')
        out.write(response.read().decode(encoding))
        out.close()
```